# Loop through directory comprised of csv files to execute a python code

Tags: python, loops

Require guidance on how to Loop through a directory to execute a block of code to each file. The code will produce three results, for e.g avg, mode and std deviation.

The files are daily files stored in the directory and therefore would like to append the three statistics generated by the loop/code daily, so end of month will have 30 columns of 3 rows stored in a data-frame:

- avg
- mode
- std deviation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` library to parse through the files of a certain directory. Here is how it works :

```
import os

for file in os.listdir('./'):
    # Your "block of code"
```

---

Comment: thanks. So when opening each csv file in the loop i could do it as such: **data = pd.read_csv("file", sep="|")** ?

Comment: Yes you can ! But be sure that there are no other files in your directory otherwise there will be an error when you will try to open a non csv file. If there are just put a condition like `if file.split('.')[-1]=='csv':` to only read the csv's